# How to read XML file line by line in Mac OS using VBA?

Tags: macos, vba

I want to read the XML file line by line in Mac OS using VBA. File are stored in specific location (Document:Test Project:Text.XML).

Can anybody suggest me how to achieve above functionality? 
If it is not possible line by line, please suggest any other way to read xml file.

Comment: Reading xml, line by line is meaning less as node information may span to multiple lines.

Comment: @Jules Can you please suggest me how to read xml file line by line or full file(all lines) or any other way?